# Having All devices show the same text and time at the same time

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, timer

I was wondering if it is possible to have a browser, ios device, android, etc phones to show the same timer, question, labels, etc.. Like how TimePlay works basically. Like as soon as the play buttons is hit the timer and the question shows to what it is on any device For example, if the timer is at 14 sec and the question is what's 4+5? that will show on all devices and browswer, and as soon as the timer goes to zero the question changes on all devices. Using Parse as a backend and programming in any code.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can give a try with Firebase. It's better in realtime database according to my knowledge. [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)

Comment: I never heard of Firebase. How does it compare with Parse

Comment: This link might help the OP. But link only-answers are not encouraged as links tend to change over time. Maybe you can describe the gist here, linking to the source.

Comment: Try one of this or you can google...
[link](https://www.quora.com/Cloud-Services/How-does-Firebase-differ-from-Parse)
[link](http://community.rubymotion.com/t/firebase-vs-parse/417)
Firebase is also a service like parse.com, but it has very fast responsing time.